# How to click checkbox after getting a value from below its preceding webelement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click a dynamic checkbox getting generated i.e "Rec136"

What i have is the  name="345551" and value="345551"

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'345551')]")).getText()
```

I tried clicking the checkbox:-

```
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'345551')]")));
```

HTML:-

```
<tr id="Rec136">
    <td align="center" width="10%">
    <input name="345551" value="345551-1" type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="10%">bnnsnjad</td>
```

After inspecting the checkbox , found path is:

```
.//*[@id='Rec136']/td[1]/input   (Need to click)
```

How to click the checkbox (.//*[@id='Rec136']/td[1]/input) after getting the element using "contains" . In short , how to click the above checkbox after getting the value "345551" ?

Comment: Can you share a little bit more HTML ?

Comment: Does the text **345551** reflects on the UI?

Comment: I am not sure if driver.findElement() returns a pure DOM element. Why do you use plain javascript to click the checkbox? Why not use the WebElement's click() method()´?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this **xpath** :

```
//tr[contains(@id,'Rec136')]/descendant::input
```

However the id is getting generated dynamically. So it is not a good practice to use these kind of ID's.

in code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'Rec136')]/descendant::input")).click();
```

If you want to click on check box with the respective name , then the xpath would be :

```
//td[contains(text(),'bnnsnjad')]/preceding-sibling::td/input
```

**code** :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'bnnsnjad')]/preceding-sibling::td/input ")).click();
```

Comment: I thinkt Little Bird tried to avoid the usage of ID and would prefer the initial posted xpath, which should point to the same element as your xpath  I think.

Comment: @JosefBiehler : What did he post in the initial phase ? Well, with the name , I think it is quite stable. this xpath `//td[contains(text(),'bnnsnjad')]/preceding-sibling::td/input`

Comment: This is awesome !!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If id is dynamic and you have the name/value then you can try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[name()='345551']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'345551')]")).click();
```

Comment: `name` is the attribute, you can't call `name()` method the way you used. Since it's an attribute you need to use @ to invoke that.

Comment: @Rajagopalan : Xpath has name() method also which internally calls name attribute . Just try it out.

Comment: @cruisepandey  I tried it's not working , are you using xpath 2.0?

Comment: @Rajagopalan : No sure how to check xpath version ?

Comment: @cruisepandey use lower-case() function, if it works, then it's xpath 2.0, If it's not then it's xpath 1.0

Comment: @Rajagopalan : then it's xpath 2.0

Comment: @cruisepandey Okay, I think that's why it works for you, For me it's xpath 1.0. I don't know how to move to xpath2.0, but let me do a little bit of investigation.